# How to make a Variable global to all keywords in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework, local-variables

```
${BEFORE_RESTART}=  Get Restart Count
```

This variable is local to one test case in robot framework. I want to access the same in other test cases of same test suite.

I tried to figure out ways using Set Global Variables But didnt work.

Comment: How did you use `Set Global Variable`? If it didn't work then you used it wrong.

Comment: Please show how you used `Set Global Variable` because that is indeed the way to create a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Set Global Variable or Set Suite Variable like this:

```
Set Global Variable    ${BEFORE_RESTART}    ${empty}
Set Suite Variable     ${BEFORE_RESTART}    ${empty}
```

Your variable will change in your testcase, when you run the

```
${BEFORE_RESTART}=    Get Restart Count
```

line.

Comment: Thanks!! that helped

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you may use Variable file ( a python file with vars) and inject it in robot execution as this is equivalent to GLOBAL scope.
python file as simple as :

```
BEFORE_RESTART=0
```

attach such file with **-V** parameter to robot execution:

```
python -m robot.run -V <path to python file> <rest of robot commands>
```

Although I would suggest to try to keep scope of variables at least limited to SUITE level (with Set Suite Variable) if your testcases shares that var within same suite.